# NHibernate versioning

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am currently interesting in creating mapping for entities with a version field. However, I'm confused about how to work with versioning in a web environment. In most examples i have seen an entity is updated within a using statement that happens instantly.

In a web example the entity gets fetched in the HTTP GET and not updated until the client invokes an HTTP POST. What I normally do in the post is to fetch the entity again, update data and store it. But that entity could have changed in the time between my GET and POST. Should I check the version field myself before i save or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think you'll need to check this yourself. One way you could do this is when you retrieve the entity in the initial get and send it back to the caller, include the version number in the response.
When you do your post, include the version number. On the server side, when you re-read the attached nHibernate entity, get the *current* version number from it. If your version number is out of date, stop the update.

Comment: This is the point where concurrency checking gets hard because you have to communicate what's changed to the user and provide a means to merge their changes.

Answer (score 2):

Version 1) could be checked manually or 2) rely on NHibernate built in versioning features and timestamp type in DB. *(SQL Server supports it - but mostlikely others DB do as well somehow)*. In the second case we have to handle `exception`.

There is detailed explanation how the concurrency could be handled in NHibernate http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency

In case that you are working with SQL Server you can create the column

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
 ...
 [Version] [rowversion] NOT NULL -- new keyword for deprecated [timestamp]
 ...
```

Then adjust the Version Mapping:

```
<version name="Version" generated="always" unsaved-value="null" type="BinaryBlob">
  <column name="Version" not-null="false" sql-type="timestamp" />
</version>
```

And you also should/need to pass the *Version* number to client and bind it on POST as well (e.g. as `base64`)

Whenever you will try to `session.Update(entity)`, which has older Version value then in DB, NHibernate will throw **`NHibernate.StaleObjectStateException`**. And only in this case you can handle it. If version will match, all will work correctly and UPDATE statement will succeed.

Comment: The create table lists `NOT NULL` but the mapping xml lists `not-null="false"`. I am not sure what a null in a version column actually means so I would try to use NOT NULL as well as `not-null="true"`...but I still have to do it